# Return a selected part of string using IBM Gateway script

Tags: javascript, api, ibm-datapower

How do I extract certain parts of a string from a whole string?

My string looks like:

```
&username=user&password=pass&client_id=cid&client_secret=secret&grant_type=password
```

I want to extract the `username` and `password` values into 2 variables.

These values can appear in any order in the string.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done this way:

```
let a  = '&username=user&password=pass&client_id=cid&client_secret=secret&grant_type=password'.split('&')
let user, passwordData
for(let i=0; i<a.length; i++){
  if (a[i].includes('username=')){
    user= a[i].substr(9)
  }
  if (a[i].includes('password=')){
    passwordData= a[i].substr(9)
  }
}

console.log(user, passwordData) // logs values
```

Comment: Just tried with the snippet provided am getting undefined in my logs. Does the same code fit into IBM Gateway script?

Comment: @AvinashAthreya  no, i provided you an example of  how to parse your string and get values based on  requirements stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Use RegEx to split your string and get value like below.

```js
let str = '&username=user&password=pass&client_id=cid&client_secret=secret&grant_type=password';

function getResult() {
  let arr = {};
  let KeyValueResult = str.replace(/[&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m, key, value) {
    arr[key] = value;
  });
  return arr;
}
let username = getResult()["username"];
let password = getResult()["password"];
let client_id = getResult()["client_id"];
let client_secret = getResult()["client_secret"];
let grant_type = getResult()["grant_type"];

console.log('username: ' + username + ' password: ' + password + ' client_id:  ' + client_id + ' client_secret: ' + client_secret + ' grant_type: ' + grant_type);
```

Function doesn't care about order. Just call with key it's give desire value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it actaully easier than that as DataPower ships the QueryString Module out-of-the-box...

```
const querystring = require ('querystring');
const qs = querystring.stringify('username=user&password=pass&client_id=cid&client_secret=secret&grant_type=password');
// returns {username: 'user' , password: 'pass', ... }
console.log('username: ' + qs.username + ' password: ' + qs.password);
```

Read the full documentation here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS9H2Y_7.5.0/com.ibm.dp.doc/querystring_js.html

Comment: you meant 
`const qs = querystring.parse('usern...`